# Servlet-mapping / Struts collision

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts, web.xml

When the user clicks a link I have to make a call to a remote (different domain) web service to get an access token and then redirect them to a different page on that remote domain. So I updated the web.xml to map a new URL pattern:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.test.TokenRequest</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myUrlPattern</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in the JSP I have:

```
<a href="/myUrlPattern" target="_blank">
  <img src="someimage">
</a>
```

When I navigate to test.jsp, I see:

```
[ServletException in:/jsp/test.jsp] ... (197,0) File "/struts-tiles.tld" not found'
```

Obviously I have verified that the struts file is there, but if I remove the mapping from web.xml, I can navigate to test.jsp and click on the link, obviously it does nothing.

I don't know where to go from - is this something I have to do in struts???

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to give ur tablib classpath in web.xml file

```
 <tag-lib>
  <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>  
   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
 </tag_lib> 

  or
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
```